# Getting "Use of unassigned local variable" C# error

Tags: c#

```
namespace FirstApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetDay(0));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static string GetDay(int daynum)
        {
            string dayname;
            switch (daynum)
            {
                case 0:
                    dayname = "sunday";
                    break;
            }
            return dayname;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if `daynum != 1` then `dayname`will not be *initialized*; add `default:`

Comment: What’s the value of `GetDay(1)`, according to your code?

Comment: `string dayname;` must be assigned, because `switch` can be never executed

Comment: The compiler knows that if `dayNum` is not `0` then the case in the switch that initialises `dayName` will be skipped, and thus `dayName` would be uninitialised when it is returned. The compiler, however does NOT know that the only place you're calling `GetDay()` is when you are passing `0` to it. So it doesn't know that `dayname` would always be initialised for this particular implementation, hence it has to give an error. The key thing here is that the compiler is deliberately dumb when it comes to deep program flow analysis.

Comment: `static string GetDay(int daynum) => datenum == 0 ? "sunday" : "Not sunday";` or alike

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of unassigned local variable c# error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230787/use-of-unassigned-local-variable-c-sharp-error)

Answer (score 0):

```
static string GetDay(int dayNum) {
  string dayname = String.Empty;
  switch(dayNum) {
   case 0:
    dayname = "sunday";
    break;
  }
  return dayname;
}
```

Comment: Why `String.Empty`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Since `GetDay()` is not declared as `static string? GetDay(int dayNum)` then if nullable checking was enabled, initialising `dayname` to `null` would give a compile error (since the code could be returning a null value). Of course, if `dayNum` is out of range, real code should throw an exception rather than returning an empty string or null.

Comment: @MatthewWatson _real code should throw an exception rather than returning an empty string or null_ exactly. Returning an empty string is rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line instead:

```
        string dayname = "";
```

that way if none of you case statements match, the function can return an empty string;

Otherwise if DayNum != 0, the function has nothing to return - which is why you are getting the error.